# Should I use training or main dataset for SVM_model.fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, training-data

I split my data into training, valuation, test.

I used the validation set in GridSearch to get best parameter `C`.

Then I used training set as `SVM_model.fit(X_train,y_train)` with the best `C`.

Is it correct?

My full code:

```
X_main, X_test, y_main, y_test = train_test_split(dataTrain, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_main, y_main,  test_size=0.2, random_state=10)

GridSearch -> Defining parameter range
svm_linear = {'C': [0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1 , 10 , 100],'kernel': ['linear']}
parameters = [svm_linear]
svc_mod = GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(), param_grid=parameters , cv=5 ,verbose=50)
svc_mod.fit(X_val,y_val)

#svc_mod.best_estimator_
print('***',svc_mod.best_params_) # -> =C=0.0001


SVM_model = svm.SVC( kernel ='linear',C=0.0001)
SVM_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: @GoldenLion "Yes"? OP fits their grid search with the validation data...

Comment: fit on the train data

Answer (score 2):

your main mistake on your fit on GridSearchCV() :
you must give main train data to GridSearchCV because GridSearchCV must **fit** on your main training data to find best parameters for  this alghorithm and this data

my edit on your code :

```
svc_mod.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: Thanks , but where I use val ? , and in last two line I fit the SVM model with the train ?

Comment: your wellcome , i think onece split data is enough . you dont need val !